# Are hashes of Merkle tree roots unique throughout whole blockchain?

Tags: merkle-tree

The "Mastering Bitcoin" book says that each block header contains a 32B long hash of the Merkle root for all the transactions it contains.

If I extract all these Merkle roots from all the blocks in the blockchain (longest branch only) and put them in a list, will that list have any duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The merkle root is a *32 byte* hash.

As the hashing operation is sha256, it is exceedingly unlikely that you will find duplicates, but it is not, strictly speaking, impossible.

Comment: The list will actually have 2 duplicates, due to the coinbase duplications before BIP30.

Comment: @PieterWuille Isn't that simply a duplicate coinbase *transaction*? Since block 91880 contains a non-coinbase transaction as well, the merkle root in the header will be different

Comment: Ah, I must have misremembered then! I thought they both had no other transactions.